# How do I get the current system date and time in C# and insert it into SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert the current date and time of system from a C# app into a SQL Server database.

In what format does C# get system date in in what will the SQL Server accept that?

Comment: Why not just insert "NOW()" in the query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp may help

Comment: A simple google search can give you an answer...

Comment: had search google and did it on many ways but the entry is not inserting into database, 
May be there is something wrong with my app or some services may be not function

Comment: It **REALLY** depends on **WHICH** database you mean by "SQL database". SQL is **just** the query language - not the actual database product...... so are you using MySQL? Postgres? Ingres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? FIrebird? Or what else??? Please tag your question appropriately!

Comment: what is your database? is it SQL Server? and what is the data type assigned for the column?

Comment: @marc_s  well i don't know much as m beginner
But i am using Microsoft SQL server managment studio for creation of database

Comment: @Damith i m using Microsoft SQL Server managment studio

datatype of column is datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can leave it to do by the database itself like below

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values (GetDate())
```

Or if you need to set the DateTime column values, you can use parameters

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values (@MyDate)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", DateTime.Now);
```

sample code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(clsConnection.getConnectionString()))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into HMS.dbo.CheckInOut(Room_No,Name,DateTime,CheckInOut) Values(02,'Name',GETDATE(),'CheckIn')", con))
{
    con.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    lblmissing.Text = "Recorded Inserted Successfully"; 
}
```

Comment: i tried it but i doesn't insert it.

command.CommandText = "insert into HMS.dbo.CheckInOut Values(02,'Name',GETDATE(),'CheckIn');";
this is the code i wrote it

Comment: Are you using sql server? what is the column data type?

Comment: "insert into HMS.dbo.CheckInOut (Column_1_Name, Column_2_Name,..) Values (2, 'Tanverr', GETDATE(), 'CheckIn')"

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Bro tried it but still not working
 when i try to insert directly from SQL its working there, but when i execute the code in c# app its not working then

Comment: @Damith data type is DateTime
yeah it is SQL server

Comment: @tanveerjan it should work, can you update the question with the code you tried?

Comment: insert into HMS.dbo.CheckInOut(Room_No,Name,DateTime,CheckInOut) Values(02,'Name',GETDATE(),'CheckIn'); @Damith

Comment: i mean C# code, not the sql statement

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(clsConnection.getConnectionString());
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            
            command.CommandText = "insert into HMS.dbo.CheckInOut Values(02,'Name',GETDATE(),'CheckIn');";
                lblmissing.Text = "Recorded Inserted Successfully";
                command.Connection = con;
                
                

                con.Open();
               
                command.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }

Comment: you are commented out `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`??? it will not insert the record

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DateTime.Now; /* to get the date time */
```

And then insert it into the SQL database using

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (Date) VALUES (@0)", DateTime.Now
```

Note that the format must match. You cannot just create a date time and insert it.

Here is the format in my Database: **2/7/2014 11:14:14 PM**. Although it is not DateTime.Now but it will tell you what is the format, it was caught a few days ago (on the 7th).

Answer (score 0):

For C#:

```
DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
```

To insert into sql-server:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(parameterName, SqlDbType.DateTime);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = dateTimeNow;
```

Answer (score -4):

If you only want to get Hours minute and second only, use

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: It is (almost) never a good idea to store a date as a string. You just take away way too much flexibility (and you are setting yourself up for a big headache when it comes to localization, timezones etc.).